# JPA equivalent of subtraction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Tried to google this a bit and found nothing close.

I'm using JPA with Hibernate in my Spring Boot project. I want to know the JPA equivalent of

```
UPDATE balance
SET amount = amount - :transactionAmount
WHERE accountId = :accountId
```

The goal of this being to perform the entire update without risking another record updating the value and losing the amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Balance b
SET b.amount = b.amount - :transactionAmount
WHERE b.accountId = :accountId
```

Remember JPQL is executed against the logical model, not the database, so names are those of the entities (read: Java class names), hence the `Balance b`. Also you need to qualify the identifiers, so `b.amount` instead of `amount`. And of course the `SET` goes before the `WHERE` :)

Comment: Oh, dear. I'm so embarrassed.